# how can i put the value into Set<UserRelative> via jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
                        url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/backend/system/userRelative/add',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            id:$("#id").val(),
                            cardNo:userCardNoAdd.val(),
                            userName:userNameAdd.val(),
                            companyName:companyNameAdd.val(),
                            departmentName:departmentNameAdd.val(),
                            userRelatives.relativeName:relativeNameAdd.val(),
                            userRelatives.relativeType:relativeTypeAdd.val(),
                            userRelatives.relativeCardNo:relativeCardNoAdd.val()},
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert('error' + textStatus + "/" + errorThrown);},
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data=='success') {
                                alert('success');
                                $("#userRelativeDIV").dialog("close");
                            } else {
                                alert('fail');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

**User and UserRelative has a one-to-many relationship; now i want to save an entity User;but i have a problem ; how can i use jquery.ajax to send an entity User to Spring Controller;how can i put the value into Set via jquery.ajax **

```
public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private long id;
 private String userName;
private Set<UserRelative> userRelatives = new HashSet<UserRelative>(0);
......}
```

public class UserRelative  implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private long id;
 private User user;
 private String relativeName;
 private String relativeType;
 private String cardNo; 
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but if I were you, I will only use AJAX to post values corresponding to user's attributes. and inside the Controller, construct the User entity and save into Model.